# How to save dynamic html-code in database for specific user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, mongodb

I have javascript code that works a lot like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nj4N4/7/

On my page it looks like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hurh.png). 
When you click on the "add a year" button, a table that looks like year2 pops upp above the previous year.

I now want this to be saved in the database so when you update the page, the specific user that is logged in still have the same quantity of years shown as before he/she updated the site (or logged out). My question is how I could do that, and where to begin. I am using the mean stack (mongodb, node, express, angular).

I have created a database named year and when you click on the "add a year" button it adds a new year in that database, but it only has an Id for now. This is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <button class="btn btn-default addyear"  ng-click="vm.addYear();" onclick="add_fields();">Add a year</button><br><br><br>
        <div class="row" >
            <div id="year6"></div>
            <div id="year5"></div>
            <div id="year4"></div>
            <div id="year3"></div>
            <div id="year2"></div>
            <div class="panel panel-default" >
                <div class="panel-heading "><B>  YEAR 1</B>
                    <a href="#" class= "show" id="hide" >Show less</a>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body hideyear1 " >
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <tr >
                                <td><b>Course code</b></td>
                                <td><b>Course name</b></td>
                                <td><b>Block</b></td>
                                <td><b>Level</b></td>
                                <td><b>HP</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>TDDD27</td>
                                <td>Webprog</td>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>6</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>TEIE06</td>
                                <td>IFP</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>A</td>
                                <td>6</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Course code</b></td>
                                <td><b>Course name</b></td>
                                <td><b>Block</b></td>
                                <td><b>Level</b></td>
                                <td><b>HP</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>

    var year = 1;
    var limit = 7;
    function add_fields() {
        year++;
        if (year == limit)  {
            exit;
        }

        else {
                var newdiv = document.createElement('div');



        if(year==2) {
                newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="panel panel-default" ><div class="panel-heading "><B>YEAR '  +year+'</B> <a href="#" class= "show" id="hide">Show less</a> </div> <div class="panel-body hideyear1 "> <div class="col-xs-6"> <table class="table table-striped"> <tr > <td><b>Course code</b></td> <td><b>Course name</b></td> <td><b>Block</b></td> <td><b>Level</b></td> <td><b>HP</b></td> </tr>  </table> </div> <div class="col-xs-6"> <table class="table table-striped"> <tr> <td><b>Course code</b></td> <td><b>Course name</b></td> <td><b>Block</b></td> <td><b>Level</b></td> <td><b>HP</b></td> </tr> </table> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> ';;
                document.getElementById('year2').appendChild(newdiv);

            }
            if(year==3) {
                newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="panel panel-default" ><div class="panel-heading "><B>YEAR '  +year+'</B> <a href="#" class= "show" id="hide" >Show less</a> </div> <div class="panel-body hideyear1 " > <div class="col-xs-6"> <table class="table table-striped"> <tr > <td><b>Course code</b></td> <td><b>Course name</b></td> <td><b>Block</b></td> <td><b>Level</b></td> <td><b>HP</b></td> </tr></table> </div> <div class="col-xs-6"> <table class="table table-striped"> <tr> <td><b>Course code</b></td> <td><b>Course name</b></td> <td><b>Block</b></td> <td><b>Level</b></td> <td><b>HP</b></td> </tr> </table> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> ';;
                document.getElementById('year3').appendChild(newdiv);

        }
            if(year==4) {
                newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="panel panel-default" ><div class="panel-heading "><B>YEAR '  +year+'</B> <a href="#" class= "show" id="hide" >Show less</a> </div> <div class="panel-body hideyear1 " > <div class="col-xs-6"> <table class="table table-striped"> <tr > <td><b>Course code</b></td> <td><b>Course name</b></td> <td><b>Block</b></td> <td><b>Level</b></td> <td><b>HP</b></td> </tr> </table> </div> <div class="col-xs-6"> <table class="table table-striped"> <tr> <td><b>Course code</b></td> <td><b>Course name</b></td> <td><b>Block</b></td> <td><b>Level</b></td> <td><b>HP</b></td> </tr> </table> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> ';;
                document.getElementById('year4').appendChild(newdiv);

            }
            if(year==5) {
                newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="panel panel-default" ><div class="panel-heading "><B>YEAR '  +year+'</B> <a href="#" class= "show" id="hide" >Show less</a> </div> <div class="panel-body hideyear1 " > <div class="col-xs-6"> <table class="table table-striped"> <tr > <td><b>Course code</b></td> <td><b>Course name</b></td> <td><b>Block</b></td> <td><b>Level</b></td> <td><b>HP</b></td> </tr> <tr> </table> </div> <div class="col-xs-6"> <table class="table table-striped"> <tr> <td><b>Course code</b></td> <td><b>Course name</b></td> <td><b>Block</b></td> <td><b>Level</b></td> <td><b>HP</b></td> </tr> </table> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> ';;
                document.getElementById('year5').appendChild(newdiv);

            }
            if(year==6) {
                newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="panel panel-default" ><div class="panel-heading "><B>YEAR '  +year+'</B> <a href="#" class= "show" id="hide" >Show less</a> </div> <div class="panel-body hideyear1 "> <div class="col-xs-6"> <table class="table table-striped"> <tr > <td><b>Course code</b></td> <td><b>Course name</b></td> <td><b>Block</b></td> <td><b>Level</b></td> <td><b>HP</b></td> </tr> <tr> </table> </div> <div class="col-xs-6"> <table class="table table-striped"> <tr> <td><b>Course code</b></td> <td><b>Course name</b></td> <td><b>Block</b></td> <td><b>Level</b></td> <td><b>HP</b></td> </tr> </table> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> ';;
                document.getElementById('year6').appendChild(newdiv);
                $(".addyear").hide();
```

**index.controller**:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Home.IndexController', Controller);

    function Controller(UserService, YearService, FlashService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.user = null;
        vm.addYear = addYear;

        initController();

        function initController() {
            UserService.GetCurrent().then(function (user) {
                vm.user = user;
            });
        }

        function addYear() {
            YearService.Create()
                .then(function () {
                    FlashService.Success('Year saved!');
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    FlashService.Error(error);
                });

        }


    }

})();
```

**year.service.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('YearService', Service);

    function Service($http, $q){
        var service =  {};

        service.Create = Create;
        return service;

        function Create() {
            return $http.post('/api/year').then(handleSuccess, handleError);
        }
```

**api/year.controller**

```
var YearService = require('services/year.service');

router.post('/', createYear);
module.exports = router;

function createYear(req, res){
   YearService.create(req.body)
        .then(function(){
            res.sendStatus(200);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        });
}
```

**services/year.service**

```
var db = mongo.db(connectionString, { native_parser: true });
db.bind('years');

var service = {};
service.create = create;


module.exports = service;

function create(yearParam) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    createYear();

    function createYear() {
        var year = yearParam;
        db.years.insert(
            year,
            function (err, doc) {
                if (err) deferred.reject(err);

                deferred.resolve();
            });


    }

    return deferred.promise;

}
```

Im sorry if this is to much code but since I don't know where to start or how to do this, I also don't know which code that is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Ok ,you need to separate the concerns, the Angular way.
It looks like you are only leveraging the $http resource requests of Angular where you could have generated the whole table with very little effort.

The goal you should have is to build a single Object of nested arrays (which we call a Model) that will hold each year's data which can easily be converted to JSON or back to an javascript Object.

Structure that can hold all of the information you need. Having a Model like this you can start building your visual elements. Based on this model. To add another year you would simply push an array of variables onto this model and your tables and visual elements update automatically through ng-repeat and ng-model directives.

Since it is much easier to manipulate a Model you can focus on the visual elements and styling instead of trying to remember if you copied all the table elements or if you have missing tags which will break the page.

Lastly a model like this can be used without any conversion directly in your $http resource request to update your database. The JSON conversion happens automatically.

You dont need the YearService, year.service, createyear deffered callbacks, or the massive javascript add_fields function.

You can simplify your whole app into two files: index.html and app.js.
Hold the fetch and save data in your main app controller as $scope functions that can be called directly from buttons on the page.

Get rid of the services and factories, just write one function saveModel(); and getModel(); and to add a year addYear() to manipulate the model.

Lastly in your html body you only need one table of one line of headers and the rows are generate from an ng-repeat. Wrap this table with a div for the years which you also ng-repeat on the years top level array.

Your array will look something like this:

```
[ "2000" : [{ course : "code", coursename : "webprog", block : "1"},
            { course : "code1", coursename : "webprog1", block : "2"}],
"2001" : [{ course : "code", coursename : "webprog", block : "1"},
            { course : "code1", coursename : "webprog1", block : "2"}]
]
```